# Is it OK to mix categorical and continuous data for SVM (Support Vector Machines)?

Tags: categorical-data, svm, mixed-type-data

I have a dataset like

```
+--------+------+-------------------+
| income | year |        use        |
+--------+------+-------------------+
|  46328 | 1989 | COMMERCIAL EXEMPT |
|  75469 | 1998 | CONDOMINIUM       |
|  49250 | 1950 | SINGLE FAMILY     |
|  82354 | 2001 | SINGLE FAMILY     |
|  88281 | 1985 | SHOP & HOUSE      |
+--------+------+-------------------+
```

I embed it into a LIBSVM format vector space

```
+1 1:46328 2:1989 3:1
-1 1:75469 2:1998 4:1
+1 1:49250 2:1950 5:1
-1 1:82354 2:2001 5:1
+1 1:88281 2:1985 6:1
```

Feature indices:

- 1 is "income"
- 2 is "year"
- 3 is "use/COMMERCIAL EXEMPT"
- 4 is "use/CONDOMINIUM"
- 5 is "use/SINGLE FAMILY"
- 6 is "use/SHOP & HOUSE"

Is it OK to train a support vector machine (SVM) with a mix of continuous (year, income) and categorical (use) data like this?

Comment: You should spell out "SVM", at least once.

Comment: Make sure you scale that data!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes! But maybe not in the way you mean.
In my research I frequently create categorical features from continuously-valued ones using an algorithm like [recursive partitioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_partitioning). I usually use this approach with the [SVMLight](http://svmlight.joachims.org) implementation of support vector machines, but I've used it with LibSVM as well. You'll need to be sure you assign your partitioned categorical features to a specific place in your feature vector during training and classification, otherwise your model is going to end up jumbly.

**Edit:** That is to say, when I've done this, I assign the first n elements of the vector to the binary values associated with the output of recursive partitioning. In binary feature modeling, you just have a giant vector of 0's and 1's, so everything looks the same to the model, unless you explicitly indicate where different features are. This is probably overly specific, as I imagine most SVM implementations will do this on their own, but, if you like to program your own, it might be something to think about!

Comment: thanks Kyle, can you be a little more specific? What do you mean "assign your partitioned categorical features to a specific place"?

Comment: @SeamusAbshere No problem! I edited my answer to address this!

Comment: I feel like I've heard that libsvm does what you're talking about automatically - any thoughts?

Comment: @SeamusAbshere I imagine you're right, but I don't know for sure. Now that I think about it, I'm not sure how it could work any other way.

Comment: Emboldened by @Kyle's answer, I wrote a Ruby library ([VectorEmbed](https://github.com/seamusabshere/vector_embed)) that does this conversion (embedding) automatically, both for categorical (using Murmur32 hashes) and continuous data. It outputs libsvm-formatted files.